# Вк бот не читает сообщения и не отвечает в лс

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Бот не видит сообщения (даже в ЛС).

***Код:***

```
import vk_api, random
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
# из лонг пулла импортируем нужные нам библиотеки.

class Server:

    def __init__(self, api_token, group_id, server_name: str="Empty"):

        # Даем серверу имя
        self.server_name = server_name

        # Для Long Poll
        self.vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=api_token)

        # Для использования Long Poll API
        self.long_poll = VkBotLongPoll(self.vk, group_id)

        # Для вызова методов vk_api
        self.vk_api = self.vk.get_api()

    def send_msg(self, send_id, message):
        """
        Отправка сообщения через метод messages.send
        :param send_id: vk id пользователя, который получит сообщение
        :param message: содержимое отправляемого письма
        :return: None
        """
        #vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message":"Привет!!!", "random_id":123456})
        self.vk_api.messages.send(peer_id=send_id, message=message, random_id = 1)

    def test(self):
        # Посылаем сообщение пользователю с указанным ID
        self.send_msg(474816854, "Hi!")

    def start(self):

            for event in self.long_poll.listen():
                print(event)
                self.test()
```

Так же не понимаю, зачем нужен `random_id`.

Comment: Из очевидного: включен ли `Long Poll` в настройках сообщества? Указаны ли типы событий для `Long Poll`? Инициализирован ли класс `Server` (и запущен ли он, естественно)?

Comment: @nomnoms12, спасибо, Long Poll был включен, но не были указаны типы событий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Укажите типы событий для `Long Poll`:

[image: Long Poll API]

---

`random_id` — это уникальный идентификатор сообщения **при отправке на сервер**.

Обязательно должен быть разный для каждого сообщения. Получить его можете с помощью функции `get_random_id` из модуля `vk_api.utils`. Нужен для того, чтобы отличать сообщения. Например, чтобы не отправить дважды при сбоях в сети.