# VkBotLongPoll.listen() никак не реагирует на сообщения

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот, long-poll

Изучаю, как делать ботов сообществ. В уроке был пример кода для этого, но у меня он ничего не заработал. Аналогичные примеры предлагали и в документации vk-api, на форумах. Вот, как примерно это выглядит:

```
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll
vk_session = VkApi(token='токен')
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, '194917248')

def main():
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        print('it works')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Я присылаю сообщения, но ничего не выводится, программа не завершает работу, исключения не выбрасываются. Когда я ошибался в id, токене или настройке сообщества хоть что-то происходило. Проверял код с таким циклом:

```
while True:
    try:
        messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": "unanswered"})
        if messages["count"] >= 1:
```

Он уже работает. Но непонятно, почему не работает первый.
Настроил всё так же, как в инструкции. Long Poll API включен, версия 5.103. vk_api.**version** == '11.8.0'
Если потребуется для решения проблемы, могу дать доступ к управлению группой. Там всё равно ничего важного нет.

Comment: Вы случайно не забыли [указать типы событий для `Long Poll`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1112778/339283)?

Answer (score -1):

```
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, '194917248')
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что `'194917248'` - это id сообщества?

Если так, то вы передали его просто как второй аргумент, но не конкретный атрибут.

Попробуйте

```
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, group_id='194917248')
```

Возможно, что у вас слушалась группа с идентификатором None по умолчанию.

Comment: Не помогает. Да и в VkBotLongPoll.__init__ вторым аргументом идёт как раз group_id

Comment: Я посмотрел в исходники `vk_api` и на самом деле не очень понял реализации.
Как мне видится, `longpoll.listen()` никогда и ничего не вернет и ваша программа завершится только в случае выброса исключения: случится переполнение генератора или соединение с сервером будет остановлено.

Попробуйте ради теста поставить `print()` внутри реализации метода `listen` прямо в цикле `for` до строчки `yield event`.

UPD: Если я правильно понял, у вас уже проблема решена, а азартный интерес остался. Мне тоже интересно, что же не так. Давайте выясним х)